# ObjectContext not adding an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm adding an entity to the object context like this

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
.
.
.
```

In a different class I've the following code

```
using (MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
  Info x = new Info();

  dbContext.AddToInfo(x);
}
```

However when I check the entities in Info in 'dbContext' after adding 'x' to it the watch  say that dbContext.Info 'Enumeration yielded no results'.

Here's a screenshot of the Watch window

[image: VS Watch Window]

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's inside of `AddToInfo(x)`?

Comment: That's a method generated by the EF Designer to add an entity to the Info's Entity.

Comment: By guessing `AddToInfo(x)` is only adding the object to the ObjectSet, I suppose you will find your object in `dbContext.YourObjectSet.Local`. After saving changes, it will effectively appear in `dbContext.YourObjectSet`. Or so I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you add a new entity, it is only present in the ObjectStateManager. For your entity to present in the ObjectSet, you need to call the dbContext.SaveChanges.

If you want to be able to enumerate through all your Entities need to query the ObjectSet and the ObjectStateManager.

```
dbContext.Infos.Union(dbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Select(e=> e.Entity).OfType<Info>)
```

(the syntax may be wrong, I convert the code from vb.net from memory only)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
using (MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
  Info x = new Info();

  dbContext.YourTableObjectSet.AddObject(x);
}
```

YourTableObjectSet is the name of the ObjectSet that represents your table.